# Export Azure AD CreatedDateTime for a list of users using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I couldn't find any info regarding (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId "upn@domain.com").Get_Item("createdDateTime") for a list of users.
Getting account creation date for single or All Users in AAD is not a solution.

I've managed to collect part of the script I'm interested in and using below code I get the date printed for all imported UPNs:

[csv import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFw80.png)

```
Connect-AzureAD

import-csv -path C:\Temp\Morsecode\F1license.csv |
ForEach-Object{
  (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.Name).Get_Item("createdDateTime") 
  }
```

[PS printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye9L0.png)

Now, I wanted to export that to csv, so I added another line which fails to export:

```
Connect-AzureAD

import-csv -path C:\Temp\Morsecode\F1license.csv |
   ForEach-Object{
  (Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectId $_.Name).Get_Item("createdDateTime") 
            
 } | Export-CSV -Path C:\Temp\Morsecode\F1license_creationDate.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What am I missing?
If anyone encountered that, or maybe have ready solution please help.

Comment: in which sense does it fail? Please be more specific

Comment: It doesn't export any data apart from number 19

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce in my environment***

*Commands for single user.*

```
$user= Get-AzureADUser   -ObjectID xxx@txxx.onmicrosoft.com
$Extension_Attributes = New-Object Psobject -Property $user.ExtensionProperty
```

Try checking its extension attribute  in single object .

```
$UserAttribues = [pscustomobject] @{
"UserPrincipalName" = $user.UserPrincipalName
"CreatedDateTime" = $Extension_Attributes.createdDateTime
}
```

*You can export the data using the following command:*

```
$UserAttribues  | Export-Csv -Path D:\UserFile.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Check the csv file in specified path:

[image]

**For all set of users, use below commands:**

```
$allUsers = get-azureaduser -All $true
$allUsers| foreach-object {
$eachuser = $_
 Converting the Dictionary to Custom Object to make use of . operator
$Extension_Attributes = New-Object Psobject -Property  $eachuser.ExtensionProperty 

$eachuser_properties = [pscustomobject] @{
"UserPrincipalName" = $eachuser.UserPrincipalName
"UserCountryName" = $eachuser.Country
"CreatedDateTime" = $Extension_Attributes.createdDateTime
}

}

#To export
$eachuser_properties | Export-Csv -Path D:\alluserFile.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

*Prints the information.*

[image]

**Then exports to CSV**

[image]